# error en el backend django al subir una imagen

Tags: django, vue.js, djangorestframework

les comento, realice este movimiento anteriormente, [268085](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/268085/error-al-subir-archivo-con-vuejs) al terminar el CRUD me di cuenta que al querer hacer una edición de cualquier registro, me mandaba el mismo error que cuando guardaba, este error sale aunque no mueva cosas de la imagen, con que yo haga una edición de cualquier otro campo, al darle guardar los cambios me sale el mismo error, alguien puede tener idea de cual sea mi problema.

Algo que no entiendo muy bien, por que razón no me deja de manera sencilla hacer ese grabado de una imagen, así como cuando subo un avatar de perfil, sin necesidad de otras cosas de conversión.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias de ante mano.

Código Completo:
**Model apps.control.models**

```
 class Movimiento(models.Model):
        tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=TIPO)
        descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=DESCRIP)
        fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)            
        arete = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)            
        sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
        madre = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='arete_madre')
        razamadre = models.ForeignKey(Raza, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='madreraza')            
        razaanimal = models.ForeignKey(Raza, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='movimiento_raza')
        imagen = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", blank=True, null=True, upload_to="ovinos")
        peso = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.arete
```

**form apps.control.form**

```
class MovimientoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(label="Tipo:", widget=forms.Select(), choices = TIPO, required=True)
    descripcion = forms.ChoiceField(label='Descripcion:', widget=forms.Select(), choices = DESCRIP, required=True)
    fecha = forms.DateField(label='Fecha:', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2018,2025)))
    arete = forms.CharField(label='Arete:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    madre = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',})
    razamadre = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',})
    peso = forms.CharField(label='Peso:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}))
    razaanimal = forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',})
    observaciones = forms.CharField(label='Observaciones:', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Observaciones',}))

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'
```

Vista
**apps.control.views**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView, ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from .models import Movimiento
from .forms import MovimientoForm
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, CreateAPIView, ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from .serializer import MovimientoSerializer
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse


class MovimientoList(ListView):
    model = Movimiento
    template_name = 'control/movimiento/listarmovimiento.html'
```

Serializer
**apps.control.serializer**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.control.models import Movimiento

class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
        import base64
        import six
    import uuid

    # Check if this is a base64 string
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
        # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
        if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
            # Break out the header from the base64 content
            header, data = data.split(';base64,')

        # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
        try:
            decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
        except TypeError:
            self.fail('invalid_image')

        # Generate file name:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] # 12 characters are more than enough.
        # Get the file name extension:
        file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

        complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )

        data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

    return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension

class MovimientoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    imagen = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True, use_url=True,required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Movimiento
        fields = '__all__'
```

Viewsets
apps.control.viewsets

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from apps.control.models import Movimiento
from apps.control.serializer import MovimientoSerializer

class Movimiento_viewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movimiento.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovimientoSerializer
```

Router
**apps.control.router**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import viewsets as viewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'mov', viewSet.Movimiento_viewsets,base_name='mov')
```

Urls
**apps.control.urls**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, re_path, include
    from .views import MovimientoList
    from .routers import router

    urlpatterns = [
        path('cerrar/', logout_then_login, name='logout'),
        path('movimiento/listar', MovimientoList.as_view(), name='listar-movimiento'),
        path('movimiento/api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Y lo demás que he puesto arriba

**Frontend** Fragmento del input en agregar

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addMovimiento()" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div align="left" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <b-form-group label="Imagen del Ovino:" label-for="">
                    <b-input-group>
                        <b-input-group-text slot="prepend" title="Imagen del Ovino"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera text-info"></span></b-input-group-text>
                        <b-form-file type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" ref="file" accept="image/*" v-on:change="getimage(event)" title="Imagen del Ovino"></b-form-file>
                    </b-input-group>
                </b-form-group>
            </div>
        </div
    </div>
</form>
```

**Función** vuejs2

```
       getimage(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
        },
        createImage(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.newMov.imagen = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        getimageUpdate(e) {
            //alert('Update')
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImageUpdate(files[0]);
        },
        createImageUpdate(file) {
            //alert('Create Update')
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.elmovimiento.imagen = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        updateMovimiento: function(id) {
            varurl = "/control/movimiento/api/mov/"+id+'/';
            this.$http.put(varurl, this.elmovimiento).then(response => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.elmovimiento = response.data;
                this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::modal', 'modal-1');
                this.showAlert2();
                this.getMovimientos();
                this.getRaza();
                this.getLote();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(error);
             })
        },
```

**fragmento del frontend en update:**

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="updateMovimiento(infoModal.id)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <b-form-group label="Imagen del Ovino:" label-for="">
            <b-input-group>
                <b-input-group-text slot="prepend" title="Imagen del Ovino"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera text-info"></span></b-input-group-text>
                <b-form-file type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" ref="file" v-model="elmovimiento.imagen" accept="image/*" v-on:change="getimageUpdate(event)" title="Imagen del Ovino"></b-form-file>
                <b-img class="img-responsive" thumbnail fluid :src="elmovimiento.imagen"></b-img>
            </b-input-group>
        </b-form-group>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Error]
[image: Erro2]

Comment: Saludos Enrique, disculpa la insistencia, ¿podrías editar la pregunta con el código que tienes actualmente, por favor?

Comment: Ya esta editada y con los códigos

Comment: perfecto, gracias por tu colaboración :D